# Unable to change label text after presenting the view controller programmatically in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

I am presenting the a view programmatically in if else statement using this code:

```
if (Condition)
{
     .....
}
else
{
   var vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("gameover") as UIViewController
   self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil) 
   finalMsg.text="Thank you" 
}
```

So the view is getting changed but I am not able to change the text of label finalMsg which belongs to the view that I changed programmatically (gameover).

I am getting error "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"

Can someone help me on this?

Comment: If else is not a loop, it's a conditional statement

Comment: At which line you are getting that error ?

Comment: When I try to change text of a label on that  view finalMsg.text="Thank you"

Comment: How you declared `finalMsg` ?

Answer (score 0):

Set the "finalMsg" of "vc":

vc.finalMsg.text = "Thank you"